# Making a gameobject disappear when i'm certain distance from it

Tags: unity-game-engine

I created a village in Unity, but it is really high quality, so I had performance issues.

I did occlusion baking and managed to improve it a bit. But Unity keeps "seeing" the village even if it has quite big walls and a lot of trees between me and the village.

I tried to make the whole city disappear when I'm too far away and reappear when I'm getting closer.

I tried with this script but it doesn't work. (Script works on AI for detecting if I'm close enough to start following me)

#### EDIT:

How the gameObject looks in the hierarchy

[image: How the gameObject looks]

Inside are all the props divided in 3 other Gameobjects(plot=fence, and budynki=buildings and props=props
(miasto is the name of the gameobject in which all prefabs are, also I moved the playercontroller to this script so it should detect the player)

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Miasto : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public float LookRadius = 240f;
    void Start()
    {
        GetComponent<Miasto>().enabled = true;
    }

    void Update()
    {
            if (Vector3.Distance(player.position, this.transform.position) > 240)
            {
                GetComponent<Miasto>().enabled = false;
            }
            else
                GetComponent<Miasto>().enabled = true;
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, LookRadius);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are disabling the script not the gameobject or its renderer.

Comment: So how can I change it to gameobject ? Should i change the name of this script or the gameobject with the city ( they have the same name)

Comment: Your script name is Miasto and their gameObject name is also Miasto?

Comment: Yes, both have the same name

Comment: is your city a child of the Miasto GameObject?

Comment: Just edited the question with screenshot, Miasto has 3 other gameobjects inside and inside each of them are diffrent props divided into categories. I want to make disappear the whole city, which mean the Miasto gameobject

Comment: @mortis20 you should take a look at [LOD in Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LevelOfDetail.html) Here is a good tutorial over it by [Brackeys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ifNyVS2_6f8)

Comment: I did, but from what i understood it requires to make a lower resolution model and i never used blender + those buildings I use are very detailed so it would be quite hard, besides i use quite a lot of diffrent prefabs so t would take a LOT of time and I do it for fun not money so i dont want to spend next 50 hours modeling few houses. Anyway, thanks for advise !

Comment: What you're doing here is introducing "Accidental Complexity". As others suggested, LOD is a better solution. You don't have to use Blender to make a 3D model of your village. You can just use the unity built-in 3D box mesh.

Comment: You can use LOD also with an "empty" model doing exactly what you want: show nothing when far away

Comment: I will give it a shot, maybe it will work better than script, thanks guys for the help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make it an LOD object with only 2 levels your object and nothing.

Comment: I agree with you. This is not an issue to be fixed by scripting. Unity already has a solution for this kind of problem. Another solution could be billboarding.

Comment: I will give it a shot, maybe it will work better than script, thanks guys for the help :)

Answer (score 3):

Try This, I disabled the meshRenderer which makes it visually dissapear:

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Miastro : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    MeshRenderer[] meshRenderer;
    public float LookRadius = 240f;

    void Start()
    {
        GetComponent<Miastro>().enabled = true;
        meshRenderer = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshRenderer>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Vector3.Distance(player.position, this.transform.position) > 240)
        {
            foreach (MeshRenderer renderer in meshRenderer) 
            {
                renderer.enabled = false;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            foreach (MeshRenderer renderer in meshRenderer)
            {
                renderer.enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, LookRadius);
    }
}
```

Comment: I got this error in Unity (it doesnt show any errors in visual studio)    (also i changed the name of the script to the same as the class)  MissingComponentException: There is no 'MeshRenderer' attached to the "Miasto" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
You probably need to add a MeshRenderer to the game object "Miasto". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.
Miastro.Update () (at Assets/Skrypty/Miastro.cs:25)

Comment: @mortis20 If it solves your issue, don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.